simple HTML dom - returns an object, instead of returning null if it doesn't find the element
im using something like:
$span = $value -> find('span', 0);
var_dump($span);

and i get:
object(voku\helper\SimpleHtmlDomBlank)#63 (2) { ["node":protected]=> NULL ["classListCache":"voku\helper\AbstractSimpleHtmlDom":private]=> NULL }

next time used:
$ul = $value -> find('ul', 0);
var_dump($ul);

and i get just (I expect):
NULL

What's the diffrent, where i made mistake?
I expect just NULL if, element don't exist. Not object.

This looks like this bug which the author has a commit they said addresses it
